# Python messing up the scandinavian characters (Ö -> Ã)

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding

I know everyone's fed up with encoding questions, but I can't figure this out.

I'm getting data from a XML-file (API) in Python. Everything is fine, but when I print the values that contain scandinavian characters, such as `Ö` or `Ä`, they get messed up:

```
Ö -> Ã
Ä -> Ã¤
```

The XML-document is encoded in UTF-8.

Here's my code. Sorry for the inconvenience.

```
# Get the data
from urllib2 import urlopen
ur = urlopen("http://www.leffatykki.com/xml/leffat")
data = ur.read()

# Replace ampersands (triggers an error)
data = data.replace('&', '&amp;')

# Loop XML
from lxml import etree
from cStringIO import StringIO

def fast_iter(context, func):
    for event, elem in context:
        func(elem)
        elem.clear()
        while elem.getprevious() is not None:
            del elem.getparent()[0]
    del context

def process_element(elem):
    try:
        name = elem.xpath('name/text( )')[0]
        year = elem.xpath('year/text( )')[0]
        print name
    except IndexError:
        temp = '...'

context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(data), tag='movie')
fast_iter(context, process_element)
```

Comment: Oh, but from the looks of the results, you simply print out the byte representation of UTF-8.

Comment: "many" is a bit facetious. There are a few well-known issues with the stdlib, and who-knows-how-many with external packages.

Comment: I've added my complete code, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I tried to download the xml in question to see what you're dealing with, and I got a corrupt gzip archive...

Comment: Yes, when accessed via browser it downloads a corrupted archive. Anyway, using the code above it returns XML. Don't ask me why. The API in question is young and not their top-priority.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to "etree.iterparse", try filling out the encoding value:

```
context = etree.iterparse(StringIO(data), tag='movie', encoding="utf-8")
```

From the itree.iterparse documentation:
"""
 |  Other keyword arguments:
 |   - encoding: override the document encoding
 |   - schema: an XMLSchema to validate against
"""

Better yet - forget that:

I've downloaded your file and played around - it seems to be working, at least for the first movie - maybe you have badly encoded characters in the file itself? It is either taht or everything is just fine, and the mess is only at your print statement - 
try using "`print name.encode("utf-8")`" - or the correct encoding of your terminal, instead of letting python try to guess it.

Comment: I actually tried both of those earlier but the output is the same.

Comment: FInd the correct encoding of your terminal  - it most likley is not utf-8. If you use Windows, it tends to use legacy DOS terminals with ancient encodings as shell, for example. For Latin-1 characterset, while the World standard is utf-8, all Windows native code uses "cp1252" encoding, BUT the DOS terminal where Python programas are run uses "cp850" - incompatible even with the one used in windows itself. What is going on is that Python could not find which is the default encoding for your terminal. Or just write the output to a file, and open it in an editor, instead of printing.